# Reset coordinate system of robot while maintaining relationship to the previous

Tags: rotation, pose, estimation, trajectory

I am currently estimating a robot's pose (3d position and rotation matrix) with an IMU and I want to reset the localizer in the middle of the run while keeping the relationship to the pose it had when the reset occurs.

Basically, at time t, I have the position and velocity in the world frame of the robot as well as the rotation matrix from the body-fixed frame to the world frame. If, I then reset the localizer at time t and set the position to the origin and the rotation matrix to the identity; how should the velocity be rotated such that I can relate the new estimated trajectory to the pose the vehicle had when it reset at time t by:

$$ \mathbf{p}^{world}_{t+n} = \mathbf{R}_{t}\mathbf{p}_{t+n}+\mathbf{p}_{t}$$
$$ \mathbf{R}^{world}_{t+n} = \mathbf{R}_{t}\mathbf{R}_{t+n} $$

where n is any index of the estimated positions after the reset at time t.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just considering it a reset, you should consider it a coordinate system transformation:

- You set the position to zero, that means that you create a transformation matrix which brings your current position to zero.
- You set the rotation matrix to the identity matrix, so you create a transformation matrix, which transforms your current rotation state to zero rotation.

You can build these matrices as the inverse of the transformation matrices you already have. These matrices can then be used to convert the velocity vector (or even the whole previous trajectory) to the new frame.

Do not do a reset by attributing a new position and rotation value, find the coordinate transformation which brings the current frame to the desired frame and use that transformation to transform all elements of the original frame.

Algorithmically, instead of

```
newPos = defaultPos
```

use

```
newPos = getTMat(oldPos, defaultPos) * oldPos
```

If you have a velocity vector in the previous coordinate frame, oldVel = (xvel, yvel, zvel) and you want to convert it to the new coordinate frame:

```
newVel = R * oldVel
```

Where R is the rotation part (3x3) of the T transformation matrix (4x4) between the two frames. Please note, that if the velocity is expresses in a different frame (e.g. the mobile robots coordinates) you will need the rotation matrix between the robot and the old frame first:

```
newVel = R_new, old * R_old, robot * oldVel
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The reason (I'm not entirely sure of this) for considering it as a reset is to make "Conditionally independent submaps created by EKF-SLAM". It is from a paper I am trying to replicate: Karlsson, Anders, et al. "Smoothing-based submap merging in large area SLAM." Scandinavian Conference on Image Analysis. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg, 2011.

Comment: The paper states the following: "A new submap is initiated when the sensor has moved a specified distance from the start of the current submap. Each submap is locally referenced, i.e., the sensor position is set to the origin and the orientation to a default rotation matrix. The covariance for the new pose is zero. The velocity of the sensor is initiated with the velocity of the sensor in the previous submap, rotated to compensate for resetting the sensor orientation."

Comment: However, the relation between the submaps are known as the submap is initiated at the last position of the previous submap. Thus, enabling me to reference them together in the same coordinate system by the relation I stated in my question.

Comment: Would you say that your approach corresponds to exactly this?

Comment: Resetting a rotation/translation or finding a transformation matrix which resets the value has the same effect on the frame. The difference is that the transformation matrix can be used to transform other values (e.g velocities) between the frames. The difference in code is essentially newPos = defaultPos or newPos = getTMat(oldPos, defaultPos) * oldPos

Comment: I do not understand what you are tryig to do. If you have the transfomration matrix, are you essentially asking how to rotate the velocity GIVEN the transfomration matrix, or how to define the transformation matrix given the coordinates in the two frames?

Comment: I think a bit of both. Sorry for the confusion as I am myself a bit confused. Your explanation makes total sense. Yesterday I asked my friend on this and he gave me his take on it, however, that has only left me more unsure.

Comment: His take was this: I think that each submap has its own coordinate system, rotated relative to each other such that the initial velocity is represented by the same vector in each submap (expressed in its coordinate system). That would explain the need to rotate the initial velocity.

Comment: The sentence about "resetting to a default orientation" probably refers to exactly that: the magnitude of the velocity is preserved, but its angle (in the coordinate system of the new submap) is reset to the default orientation used for initial velocity in all submaps.

Comment: The choice of initial velocity direction should be arbitrary, or (if you know the direction of gravity), you could align the XY-plane such that it is horizontal in the world (this still allows an arbitrary rotation about the Z axis, of course).

Comment: However, I doubt the correctness of his answer.

Comment: It  makes sense. All submaps have a ther own coordinate system and the transfomration matrix between them should be known as their are static (I assume). So transforming the velocity from one frame to another is a must, since the velocity as a vector gets rotated when the swithcing frames and you need the velocity in the new frame.

Comment: So you are asking who to transform the velocity given the transformation matrix

Comment: Yes! So assuming I initiate the vehicle orientation in the new submap as R0 and position to 0. Given that all information from the previous submap is available, that is it also was initiated with R0 and that the last position and orientation of the vehicle of that submap (which is where the new submap is initiated) is known.

Comment: Do we agree that newPos = getTMat(oldPos, defaultPos) * oldPos corresponds to T_new = T_default * T_old^-1 * T_old = T_default where R in newVel = R * oldVel is from  T_default * T_old^-1?

Comment: And that oldPos is the transformation from vehicle frame to submap frame while the velocity is described in submap frame.

Comment: no, there is a difference between position and transformation

Comment: pos is a vector Transfomrations are 4x4 matrices

Comment: Pos is the upper right 3x1 of the transformation matrix.  They are the same.